# How can I prevent a console error with the following code? (It says the given id is not a function)

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting an error because my javascript says that the element declaring my ID is not a function. Thank you in advance to anyone that can help. I am sure it is a simple solution. My goal is to hide one form while the "single" radio button is clicked. (Ignore the "arm all" text, I'm not sure how it got there or how to take it off).
EDIT: I have changed the function names but it seems i am still having the same issue.

```js
// This links form1/form2 to hide & display - onclick for group or single radio buttons

function single(id, text, btn) {
  var groupForm = document.getElementById('form2');
  var singleForm = document.getElementById('form1');
  groupForm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  singleForm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function group() {
  var groupForm = document.getElementById('form2');
  var singleForm = document.getElementById('form1');
  singleForm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  groupForm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
    <div id="form2" class="form">
      <select name="sendingfrom" class="click-op">
        <option value="group-select">arm</option>
        <option value="group-select">all</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="form1" class="form">
      <select name="sendingfrom" class="click-op2">
        <option value="group-select">waist</option>
        <option value="group-select">shoulder</option>
        <option value="group-select">elbow</option>
        <option value="group-select">wrist_angle</option>
        <option value="group-select">wrist_rotate</option>
        <option value="group-select">left_finger</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--onclick value links to javascript-->
<input class="radio-group" type="radio" id="group" name="group-or-single" value="group" onclick="group()">
  <label class="text-group" style="color: black; padding-left: 0px;" for="group">Group</label>

<!--onclick value links to javascript-->
<input class="radio-single" type="radio" id="single" name="group-or-single" value="single" onclick="single()">
  <label class="text-single" style="color: black; padding-left: 0px;" for="single">Single</label>
</div>
```

Comment: your function is single() and group(), but you called with single2() and group2() in your onclick

Comment: I made you a snippet. You need to use the correct function names and IDs. You have completely mixed form3,form4, form1, form2 etc

Comment: If you have more forms etc, use a class and use relative addressing using closest

Comment: Silly me, I must've mixed up the wrong code, I have about 5 different forms and must've gotten lost by the time I got to JavaScript. I will revise. Thank you!

Comment: I seem to still be having the same issue with the edit I posted above..

Answer (score -1):

You can use the try catch finally statement, but first in the HTML is the names of the function wrong written. This porblem you cannot solve with the solution i mentioned, only if you using eventlisteners in the javascript code.

In this snippet I corrected the misspeled function names, and i made the try catch blocks for you as an exmaple.

```js
// This links form1/form2 to hide & display - onclick for group or single radio buttons
function single(id, text, btn) {
  try {
    var groupForm = document.getElementById('form2');
    var singleForm = document.getElementById('form1');

    groupForm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    singleForm.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  catch {
    console.log("does not work");
  }
}

function group() {
  try {
    var groupForm = document.getElementById('form2');
    var singleForm = document.getElementById('form1');

    singleForm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    groupForm.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  catch {
    console.log("does not work");
  }
}
```

```html
    <div id="form3" class="form">
        <select name="sendingfrom" class="click-op2">
            <option value="group-select">waist</option>
            <option value="group-select">shoulder</option>
            <option value="group-select">elbow</option>
            <option value="group-select">wrist_angle</option>
            <option value="group-select">wrist_rotate</option>
            <option value="group-select">left_finger</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<!--onclick value links to javascript-->
<input class="radio-group2" type="radio" id="group2" name="group-or-single" value="group" onclick="group()">  
<label class="text-group2" style="color: black; padding-left: 0px;" for="group">Group</label>

<!--onclick value links to javascript-->
<input class="radio-single2" type="radio" id="single2" name="group-or-single" value="single" onclick="single()">  
<label class="text-single2" style="color: black; padding-left: 0px;" for="single">Single</label>
javascript
html
```

Use Try Catch statement. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch?retiredLocale=hu)